# object not locked by thread before notify() in Foreground Service Notification

Tags: android, notify, foreground-service

From android O you cant create simple background service, it has to be foreground, so I followed a tutorial and built one, but, I got this error:

```
    Unable to start service ...SMSService@302fa17 with Intent 
{ cmp=...SMSService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: 
object not locked by thread before notify()
```

I saw some other topics on this, but those are all for old Notifications

Here is my code:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                .setContentText("Content Text")                                                                                 
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check)
                .setContentIntent(mPendingIntent)
                .build();

            startForeground(1, mNotification);
            mNotification.notify();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to call `notify` on specific object it wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.

Since you are not locking any thread, you don't have to use `notify()`. Remove `mNotification.notify();`.

As for displaying notification `startForeground(1, notification);` is enough

Comment: Wow, thx actually I just found that video tutorial and there wasn't .notify() on the end, I don't know where I got it from :)